# Powershell - Text file is not written to

Tags: powershell

Good evening,

I'm hardly experienced in programming, but every now and then I try to build the things I need myself.

What do I want to achieve with the script?
This script should read a text file with words.
There is one new word per line. When reading the script should look if the word has between 3 and 16 letters. If it has less than 3 or more than 16, then the word is skipped. But if it is between the 3 and 16, then the word will be saved in a new Text_File. Again, I would love a new word every line.

Here is what I created.
Please don't judge my script too hard.

```
$regex = '[A-Z][a-z]{3,16}'

foreach ($line in Get-Content -Path C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\namecheck\\words.txt)
{
    if($line -match $regex)
    {
        Out-File -FilePath C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\namecheck\\sorted.txt -Force
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the words are not written to a file. However, the file is created and the script also takes a little while to finish. So from my point of view something seems to happen.

Comment: Use Select-String which has a Path and Pattern Property.  The Pattern is a RegEx expression.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'[A-Z][a-z]{3,16}'` is only accounting for words that are of length *3+*. That would be your first issue, and your second one is your export. `Out-File` isn't being told what you want to export. So, either provide it the a value via pipeline input, or using `-InputObject`:

```
$path   = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\namecheck\'
$stream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new("$path\words.txt")

while ($line = $stream.ReadLine())
{
    if ($line.Length -gt 3 -and $line.Length -lt 16)
    {
        Out-File -FilePath "$path\sorted.txt" -InputObject $line -Append -Force
    }
}

$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Although, a `foreach` loop is the fastest of the loops, when using `Get-Content` it still has to wait for the completion of the content gathering before it can move through the list. Only mentioning this since you said that the script takes quite a bit and without knowing the size of your `words.txt` file, im left to assume that's the cause.

With that said, using `[System.IO.StreamReader]` should speed up that reading of the file as you'll get to read and iterate through the file at the same time; with a while loop that is.

Comment: I thank you very much! I have been able to learn a lot through it and will also apply it in the future so. I wish you a pleasant evening!

Comment: @adorableAppa, please consider marking this a solution to your question.